# blocked user Json Query for mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have three Post in my collection of three different User
I am trying to fetch the post in my Views Session (Html, Css) Part
But I need to filter the other two post Posted from other two User
because I have some block functionality in my View Section. So all post are
allowed but the user I have blocked her/his post not visible to me and mine to him.

BlockedByUser : (This is my Post Json Data)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("591729b52bb30a19afc9b89d"),
"createdTime" : ISODate("2017-05-13T15:43:49.381Z"),
"isDeleted" : false,
"Message" : "Message Two",
"postedBy" : ObjectId("598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b"),
"recipient" : [ 
    ObjectId("598ae453b3bf0b85f92ee331"), 
    ObjectId("5910691ae2bcdeab80e875f0")
],
"updatedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-20T09:24:39.124Z")
}
```

Below two user Post Data that I have blocked And 
In his recipient Array Key stores my Id recipient [598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b]

Block User One :

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("591729b52bb30a19afc9b89d"),
"createdTime" : ISODate("2017-05-13T15:43:49.381Z"),
"isDeleted" : false,
"Message" : "Message One",
"postedBy" : ObjectId("598ae453b3bf0b85f92ee331"),
"recipient" : [ 
    ObjectId("598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b"), 
    ObjectId("5910691ae2bcdeab80e875f0"),
    ObjectId("598ac93cb3bf0b85f92ece44"),
],
"updatedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-20T09:24:39.124Z")
 }
```

Same as above
Block User Two :

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("591729b52bb30a19afc9b89d"),
"createdTime" : ISODate("2017-05-13T15:43:49.381Z"),
"isDeleted" : false,
"Message" : "Message One",
"postedBy" : ObjectId("598ac93cb3bf0b85f92ece44"),
"recipient" : [ 
    ObjectId("598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b"), 
    ObjectId("5910691ae2bcdeab80e875f0"),
    ObjectId("598ae453b3bf0b85f92ee331")
],
"updatedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-20T09:24:39.124Z")
 }
```

This is Block Collection that I have created and two blocked user Id with blockUserId key
Block Details One :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("598da2f0b88b0c2b0c735234"),
"blockUserId" : ObjectId("598ae453b3bf0b85f92ee331"),
"blockById" : ObjectId("598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b"),
"updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-08-11T12:28:32.145Z"),
"createdDate" : ISODate("2017-08-11T12:28:32.145Z"),
"isBlock" : "true",
"__v" : 0
```

Block Details Two

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("598da558b88b0c2b0c735236"),
"blockUserId" : ObjectId("598ac93cb3bf0b85f92ece44"),
"blockById" : ObjectId("598adbefb3bf0b85f92edc3b"),
"updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-08-11T12:38:48.772Z"),
"createdDate" : ISODate("2017-08-11T12:38:48.772Z"),
"isBlock" : "true",
"__v" : 0
  }
```

I have fetch these blocked collection and store two user blockUserId id in array
arrOne = ["598ae453b3bf0b85f92ee331", "598ac93cb3bf0b85f92ece44"]

And i am applying this query in mongoose db:

```
  query = {$or:  [{$and: [{ $or: [{ postedBy: req.params.id},
                                           {recipient: req.params.id}
                                          ]
                                    }, { createdTime: { $gt: endTime, $lt: startTime } }
                                  ]},{postedBy: {$ne: arrOne}}
                                ]
                          };

                }
```

But it will return undefined value
I am trying to fetch only my Post or Other user Post that not Blocked my Me, And Blocked User Post will not visible to me

Answer (score 0):

I have to Implement where clause and it works

```
 var query = { $and: [{ $or: [{ postedBy: req.params.id }, { recipient: req.params.id }] }, { "createdTime": { $gt: endTime, "$lt": startTime } }] };

 CollectionName.find(query).where('postedBy').nin(blocklist).exec(function(err, response);
```